# Disabling bundling minification for specific file extension

Tags: bundling-and-minification, dotless

I'm in the process of switching my site over to less and I was wanting to continue the use of `Web.Optimization` however, it fails on compiling less.  Is there a way to register `.less{}` as the processor for this or simply tell it to bundle, but not minify anything with a `.less` extension?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this guide to [bundling and minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).  It contains an example on bundling LESS files.

Essentially you create a class that implements `IBundleTransform`

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

public class LessTransform : IBundleTransform
{
    public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
    {
        response.Content = dotless.Core.Less.Parse(response.Content);
        response.ContentType = "text/css";
    }
}
```

With this and `CssMinify` you can then create a bundle.

```
var lessBundle = new Bundle("~/My/Less").IncludeDirectory("~/My", "*.less");
lessBundle.Transforms.Add(new LessTransform());
lessBundle.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
bundles.Add(lessBundle);
```