# Bundled CSS file is blank in Web Forms project

Tags: asp.net, webforms, bundling-and-minification

Overview: I am trying to get Bundling and Minification to work with an existing Asp.Net Forms website. I have everything set up and it works fine in debug. All the appropriate links are generated and my css works great; however, every time I do a release build, or just simply EnableOptimization it generates a good looking link in the correct format, but it is just a blank page so there is no css.

I followed the tutorial here: [link](http://igorzelmanovich.blogspot.com/2012/09/using-aspnet-bundling-and-minification.html)

Here is the code I am using:

Global.asax.cs

```
       private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //Private Website code removed for post

                Bundles.Register();
            }
```

Bundles.cs   (File called from application_start)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Optimization;
    using System.Web.UI;

    namespace NopSolutions.NopCommerce.Web.Optimization
    {
        public class Bundles
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Registers Bundles
            /// </summary>
            public static void Register()
            {
                var lessBundle = new Bundle("~/Bundles/fhm/product/Less").Include("~/Content/themes/fhm/product/*.css");
                BundleTable.Bundles.Add(lessBundle);
            }

            public static void RenderStyle(Page page, String bundle)
            {
                var code = System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render(bundle);
                page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(code.ToHtmlString()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Product Page code where I call the render function

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                //render css style

                Bundles.RenderStyle(this, "~/Bundles/fhm/product/Less");

            }
```

Anybody have any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: It's probably failing because of your Less files (so it'll work in debug mode but not release/EnableOptimizations). If so, you'll need a custom Transform like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417388/disabling-bundling-minification-for-specific-file-extension.

Comment: I actually had all that implemented, but couldn't get that to work either, so for the time being I was just starting out with basic css files. I am targeting only the .css file in the directory not the less files for this particular issue. That is what is so strange to me. In debug it works great and adds a link to all the .css files in the directory, and in release it generates a proper looking link ../less?v=...   but that file renders blank, so I am wondering if I am missing something in the web.config maybe? I really am at a loss.